# How can I encode string in file content?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is what I did before in form1 constructor:

```
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1255);
page = client.DownloadString("http://rotter.net/scoopscache.html");
```

client = WebClient variable
page = string variable

But I changed it and I'm doing in form1 constructor:

```
page = OffLineDownload.offlineHtmlFile1();
```

Now page have the same content as before but without downloading it.
How can I get encoding to 1255 now since some of the content in page is in Hebrew?

I tried now this:

```
page = Encoding.GetEncoding(1255).ToString();
page = OffLineDownload.offlineHtmlFile1();
```

But it's not working i got error later since the content is not in hebrew yet but some symbols and chars more like gibrish.

The offline class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace ScrollLabelTest
{
    class OffLineDownload
    {
        static string offLineHtmlBeforeChanged;
        static string OffLineHtmlAfterChanged;

        public static string offlineHtmlFile1()
        {
            offLineHtmlBeforeChanged = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\news\news1.htm");
            return offLineHtmlBeforeChanged;
        }

        public static string offlineHtmlFile2()
        {
            OffLineHtmlAfterChanged = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\news\news2.htm");
            return OffLineHtmlAfterChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whast does OffLineDownload.offlineHtmlFile1() do?

Comment: @RQDQ My crystal ball says it's something that loads a html file from disk. The problem being that it doesn't use client anymore and it's not handling the encoding properly

Comment: RQDQ added the code of the offline class to my question. I wanted to simulate like i downloaded with webclient the html file content to a string and then saved it to the hard disk. Instead i want to use an html file i already downloaded on my own from the hard disk. This is for tests. I need it to be just like the WebClient idea. But instead downloading the file using it from the hard disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString

```
byte[] bytes = this.DownloadDataInternal(address, out request);
string @string = this.GuessDownloadEncoding(request).GetString(bytes);
```

which is equivalent to

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
string @string = Encoding.GetEncoding(1255).GetString(bytes);
```

Although as Hans points out, it's better to do this in one go

```
string @string = File.ReadAllText(filename, Encoding.GetEncoding(1255));
```

Comment: Please recommend StreamReader or File.ReadAllText, they both take an Encoding argument in their overloads and require a lot less memory.